# Circular Buffer with specified expiration time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have to develop a client that must do its stuff and send files to a server. The client connects to the server via a handshake (send request, wait ACK, etc.); if the server denyes the connection or the connection failed in the meantime, the client must store the message/file in a local circular buffer. A message will be deleted from the buffer after a specified time. The buffer has a specified size/capacity.

The circular part is easy, but how do i make the message time life. So far, the best thing i could come out with was a DelayedQueue<"X"> (with some wrapping), but X must implement java.util.concurrent.Delayed and I don't want to tamper with X or have access to it's source-code.

EDIT: DelayedQueue keeps the elements internally until a specified time expires, so I misunderstood its sfecification.

Comment: You could create a wrapper for `X` which would implement `Delayed`.

Comment: I don't see how a `DelayQueue` would serve your purpose here. `DelayQueue` doesn't delete elements after expiration. On the contrary, it only allows access to expired elements. See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

Comment: Thanks for clear up on the delayQueue. The problem persist then. I found this in the meanwhile: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: Yes, Guava has a very nice caching library. Not quite a circular buffer, but it will do automatic expiration.